# Import issues in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to execute this code in Visual Studio Code, the code works, my problem is related to the import of numpy; the other imports are working.

```
import codecs
    from operator import le
    import string
    from struct import unpack
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
    import struct
    import numpy as np



def on_connect1(client1,  userdata1, flags1, rc1):
    
    client1.subscribe("MYTOPIC")

def on_message1(client1, userdata1, msg1):
    #print(msg1.topic+" "+ "TERMORESISTENZA: "+str(msg1.payload))
    Byte_Order = '<' # little-endian
    Format_Characters = 'f' # float (4 bytes)
    data_format = Byte_Order + Format_Characters
    r = np.array(list(struct.iter_unpack(data_format, msg1.payload)), dtype=float)
    print(r)
```

When I run the code it returns me this error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Windows Command Prompt to install numpy  with the command:

```
pip install numpy
```

and solved the problem